# HtmlUnit failed to execute JS with website using Telerik controls or MS ajax in general

Tags: java, html-parsing, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to parse data from a website that using MS Ajax toolkit. When the code run, tons of exception has been thrown. I also tried to use CHROME as browser version with HtmlUnit but it does not help.
Any ideas?

My code:

```
public class MainPage {
final static String baseURI = "http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/cpi/DefendantList.aspx";
final static WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);    
static HtmlPage currentPage = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {                
    try {                       
        // java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        final HtmlPage mainPage = webClient.getPage(baseURI);
        final HtmlForm searchForm = mainPage.getFormByName("form1");

        searchForm.getInputByName("rtbDefLastName").setValueAttribute("Smith");
        searchForm.getInputByName("rtbDefFirstName").setValueAttribute("John");

        final HtmlPage resultPage = searchForm.getInputByName("btnSrchByDefName").click();              
        System.out.println(resultPage.asText());                            
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And the output:

```
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/COURTS/SMCApp.css' [15:2] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "HTML". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>, <HASH>, ".", ":", "[", <S>.)
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/COURTS/SMCApp.css' [15:2] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/WebResource.axd?d=LMlbvM4qfEdzrlKVqIc-8mfNXM4PRJKfxIOMA8AV9PNLbn8G0v4aRHZWRGu2jfQxV_Ct0PNGkEjJ2YhGr40zd88yNUBWOMCpl84P3uR3Hu_GU0ul5VRWUXd5JszpaKtypLmwjMIyXOr3t6R-mMUsu2ukvVE1&t=633746128680000000' [5:1] Error in style rule. (Invalid token ".". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>.)
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/WebResource.axd?d=LMlbvM4qfEdzrlKVqIc-8mfNXM4PRJKfxIOMA8AV9PNLbn8G0v4aRHZWRGu2jfQxV_Ct0PNGkEjJ2YhGr40zd88yNUBWOMCpl84P3uR3Hu_GU0ul5VRWUXd5JszpaKtypLmwjMIyXOr3t6R-mMUsu2ukvVE1&t=633746128680000000' [5:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/WebResource.axd?d=-NPRlHTVZOXOItWVoljD3-5QEqyuzmrc_N5sqREwsKSubbs3xFynzoyWV9KKr_ebcTtV3i1Gryofr1ihfTjh3Fl4DRZHIfs1BQqGP1nWnoWCJUG8_OpYA-eDNTEOAGIsHV2QkguThgv2DKkL0&t=633746128680000000' [5:1] Error in style rule. (Invalid token ".". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>.)
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: 'http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/WebResource.axd?d=-NPRlHTVZOXOItWVoljD3-5QEqyuzmrc_N5sqREwsKSubbs3xFynzoyWV9KKr_ebcTtV3i1Gryofr1ihfTjh3Fl4DRZHIfs1BQqGP1nWnoWCJUG8_OpYA-eDNTEOAGIsHV2QkguThgv2DKkL0&t=633746128680000000' [5:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[162] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "Validators" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100#162)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "Validators" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100#162)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:210)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:804)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:869)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:845)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.executeOnChangeHandlerIfAppropriate(HtmlInput.java:491)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.setValueAttribute(HtmlInput.java:94)
    at MainPage.main(MainPage.java:27)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "Validators" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100#162)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:609)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 17 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "Validators" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100#162)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
    at script.ValidatorOnChange(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100:162)
    at script.anonymous(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=NT3AT2bWfwLom1kHaizOG9d2hL1e26kfOo4ELbGnwf_XtVYj3DpkxtzewLCDFZ6ddnSK7Q9EQPbGQqmZgSgnaaxJQlwmqMXpv7C5gFvwzHiRihCfdK25rhDzWBjlKrs7YZhXhwP5c384PDlQ0&t=ffffffff9f6f7100#97(Function):1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:609)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:210)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:804)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:869)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:845)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.executeOnChangeHandlerIfAppropriate(HtmlInput.java:491)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.setValueAttribute(HtmlInput.java:94)
    at MainPage.main(MainPage.java:27)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

  function anonymous(event) {
      ValidatorOnChange(event);
  }
```

======= EXCEPTION END ========

```
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController processSynchron
INFO: Re-synchronized call to http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/cpi/DefendantList.aspx
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[729] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "disabled" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43#729)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "disabled" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43#729)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:177)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:237)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:804)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:869)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.doClickFireClickEvent(HtmlElement.java:1311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1253)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1205)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1160)
    at MainPage.main(MainPage.java:30)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "disabled" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43#729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:609)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    ... 18 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "disabled" from undefined (http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43#729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
    at script.Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormElementActive(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43:729)
    at script.Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormElementClick(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=wAKJQuapfi2h0tvgddshu6GwSBoo0uJ-Q4zq1fpZG1ZOiNZgZZNomCn_OChvdWzXkxwIbSpMmitsYmDHmDpi-_Muj2-QmYqFjgrU54gChUB4h0YeDFGq7JyV0GIClurbdmC9pRNWwqRbk5gkFzybU7XnF9F4YUtiRPHHsC0TgYUJHhHR0&t=ffffffffdca80a43:751)
    at script(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=GzSW1c3NKsncPwlvGy3qGT-vozDnuoTbJRITSlPr6OEXzpdb1saFCmLwjRyqYfH5pta6HhEtCCU0x1VKNwmwJGlYwl2L_LdE-PxNHQjfNmEnmdhuyKvS5W28hsds4a5GmaIHjebqkMQ1yQVwZheqwC9K9wwuMr2kLfxJsg2&t=ffffffffdca80a43:47)
    at script(http://web1.seattle.gov/courts/CPI/ScriptResource.axd?d=GzSW1c3NKsncPwlvGy3qGT-vozDnuoTbJRITSlPr6OEXzpdb1saFCmLwjRyqYfH5pta6HhEtCCU0x1VKNwmwJGlYwl2L_LdE-PxNHQjfNmEnmdhuyKvS5W28hsds4a5GmaIHjebqkMQ1yQVwZheqwC9K9wwuMr2kLfxJsg2&t=ffffffffdca80a43:2948)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:609)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:616)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:985)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:177)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:237)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:804)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:738)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:869)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:602)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.doClickFireClickEvent(HtmlElement.java:1311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1253)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1205)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1160)
    at MainPage.main(MainPage.java:30)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

  function (e) {
      return handler.call(element, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(e));
  }
```

======= EXCEPTION END ========

```
Nov 12, 2013 6:05:12 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
```

It seems that the AJAX call was made, but there are some exception when the grid is being generated cause no data in front end.

Comment: Appears to be JavaScript errors. For one example, it's trying to read a property `Validators` from an undefined variable. If you look at the JavaScript, there are several calls to `Validators` properties. I'd suggest debugging the JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: I already did that, No JS errors, the website works fine with IE, Chrome, and FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the way to make it work. There're 2 things to consider here:

1. This website uses Microsoft AJAX toolkit for AJAX calls, which is not well supported with HtmlUnit library. I've tried different browser version and only one can work is CHROME.
2. Need to call waitForBackgroundJavaScript after making AJAX calls. I can get the data with:

`webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000);`

Comment: As you can see in the documentation 2.15: It is "Experimental API" and might not work fully yet and also may change in next release. But another approch with the same effect is to poll the page until something expected happens.